# Por que palavras como "Grêmio / Grémio" admitem acentos circunflexo e agudo?

Tags: diferenças, acentuação

Dependendo da localidade a acentuação das palavras a seguir é diferente.

> Amazônia(Português Brasil) / Amazónia(Português Portugal e outro países);
>   Grêmio(Português Brasil) / Grémio(Português Portugal e outro países).

Por que palavras como "Grêmio / Grémio" admitem acentos circunflexo e agudo?

Comment: Baita palavra pra dar de exemplo =)